# Why is it not possible to use "Using static" feature with private enum? Is there any alternative?

Tags: c#, enums, access-modifiers, c#-6.0

I have this class where I use a private enum. I would like to use C# 6 "Using static" feature, like the following:

```
using static ConsoleForSimpleTests.Foo.MyEnum;

namespace ConsoleForSimpleTests
{
    public class Foo
    {
        private enum MyEnum { I, DonT, Want, This, To, Be, Public }

        private MyEnum value;

        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            switch (value)
            {
                    case I:
                    case DonT:
                    case Want:
                    case This:
                    case To:
                    case Be:
                    case Public:
                        break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

NOTE: This does not compile and I understand why, it is due to the protection level for MyEnum. If I change the access modifier to either internal or public it works. What I wonder is if this is simply not possible and, if so, why is this not possible?

Comment: Sorry, I clearly skipped over that part of the question.

Comment: @BJ Myers `using static` does work for enum values indeed. The problem here is the access modifier. If you change  the private enum to be internal or public it works

Comment: @taquion You're right, my bad - I didn't read your question closely enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that were possible, and you had some other class in the same file, the symbols that you imported wouldn't be visible from that class.

That would be confusing; this is probably why that doesn't work.